# Dialog Box is not popping out

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I am new in android so i dont know correctly to code thats why my code looking very messy sorry for that
Question:
When i click on issue button nothing happens so my question is to what i have to  do so that when i click on issue button a dialog box have to appear with different message as compared to my previous dialog which is alertuserabouterror() and i dont want to create another AlertUserAboutError.java class again

Thanks in advancce

MainActivity.this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private Button issueButton;
private Button reissueButton;
private Button returnButton;
private EditText mEditText;
public AlertDialogFragment malert;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient mClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    issueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.issueid);
    reissueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reissueid);
    returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnid);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    issueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             new AlertDialogFragment.thads();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        alertuserAboutError();
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_about) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

   return true;
}

public void alertuserAboutError() {
    final AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
}}
```

AlertDialogFragment.java

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

private EditText editQuantity;
private EditText editQuantity2;
private TextView text;
Database data;



@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    editQuantity = new EditText(getActivity());
    editQuantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
            .setMessage("Please Enter TIME")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", this)
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null)
            .setView(editQuantity)
            .create();


}



@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {

    String date=editQuantity.getText().toString();
    try{ editQuantity.setText(" ");

        int newdate=Integer.parseInt(date);
        if(newdate>0) {
            data.putreturn(newdate);
            Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "Date Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter a valid number ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText( getActivity() ,"Date Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


public static class thads extends AlertDialogFragment{


    private EditText editQuantity2;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        editQuantity2 = new EditText(getActivity());
        editQuantity2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                .setMessage("Please Enter TIME")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", this)
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null)
                .setView(editQuantity2)
                .create();


    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom AlertDialogBoxes that are much easy to use as compared to default alertdialog boxes or create another AlertDialogBOx